# rearrange from specific string into respective column

Tags: awk

I'm trying to rearrange from specific string into respective column.
etc:

```
126N (will be sorted into "Normal" column)
Value 1 (the integer will be concatenated with 126)
```

Resulting :

```
N=Normal
126 @ 1
```

Here is the input

```
(N=Normal, W=Weak)
Value 1
126N,
Value 3
18N,
Value 4
559N, 562N, 564N,
Value 6
553W, 565A, 553N,
Value 5
490W,
Value 9
564N,
```

And the output should be

```
W=Weak
490 @ 5
553 @ 6

A=Absolute
565 @ 6

N=Normal
126 @ 1
18 @ 3
559 @ 4
562 @ 4
564 @ 4
553 @ 6
564 @ 9
```

Let me know your thought on this.

I've tried this script, I'm still figuring out to concatenating the value

```
cat input.txt | sed '/^\s*$/d'  | awk 'BEGIN{RS=","};match($0,/N/){print $3"c"$2}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/;/g' | sed 's/W//g;s/N//g;s/S//g'
```

And some of it, are missing

Comment: Why does I not see  `18 @ 3` in Normal?  You have `564 @ 9`.

Comment: Can you also have line like this `231W, 141N, 553N`?

Comment: Yeah, some of it

Comment: Then you should update you question with this type of example as well.

Comment: alright, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want using `gnu awk`
IT will work with any number of letters, not just `A N W`

```
awk -F, '
!/Value/ {
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
        hd=substr($i,length($i),1);
        arr[hd][++cnt[hd]]=($i+0" @ "f)}
    }
    {split($0,b," ");f=b[2];} 

END {  
    for (i in arr)  { print "\n"i"\n---";
        for (j in arr[i]) {
            print  arr[i][j]}}
}' file


A
---
565 @ 6

N
---
562 @ 4
564 @ 4
553 @ 6
564 @ 9
126 @ 1
18 @ 3
559 @ 4

W
---
553 @ 6
490 @ 5
```

Comment: Many thanks, this should be okay, it's really helpful. Have a great day

Comment: @user10254032 You are welcome.  Shorten some by removing not needed BEGIN block.

Comment: @user10254032 Found a big error, was using same array twice.  Now fixed and correct result :)

Comment: @user10254032 fixed so that it should work with any number/letter combination.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this really helps me, Jotne

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative in `awk` would be:

```
awk -F',| ' '
    $1 == "Value" {value = $2; next} 
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i~"N$")
            N[substr($i, 1, length($i) - 1)] = value
        if ($i~"W$") 
            W[substr($i, 1, length($i) - 1)] = value
      }
    }
    END {
        print "W=Weak"
        for (i in W)
            print i, "@", W[i]
        print "\nN=Normal"
        for (i in N)
            print i, "@", N[i]
    }
' file
```

(**note:** this relies on knowing the wanted headers are `W=Weak` and `N=Normal`. If would take a few additional expression if the headers are subject to change.)

**Output**

```
$ awk -F',| ' '
>     $1 == "Value" {value = $2; next}
>     { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
>         if ($i~"N$")
>             N[substr($i, 1, length($i) - 1)] = value
>         if ($i~"W$")
>             W[substr($i, 1, length($i) - 1)] = value
>       }
>     }
>     END {
>         print "W=Weak"
>         for (i in W)
>             print i, "@", W[i]
>         print "\nN=Normal"
>         for (i in N)
>             print i, "@", N[i]
>     }
> ' file
W=Weak
490 @ 5

N=Normal
18 @ 3
126 @ 1
559 @ 4
562 @ 4
564 @ 9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR%2 { val = $NF; next }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        num  = $i+0
        abbr = $i
        gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]/,"",abbr)
        list[abbr] = list[abbr] num " @ " val ORS
    }
}
END {
    n = split("Weak Absolute Normal",types)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        name = types[i]
        abbr = substr(name,1,1)
        print abbr "=" name ORS list[abbr]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
W=Weak
553 @ 6
490 @ 5

A=Absolute
565 @ 6

N=Normal
126 @ 1
18 @ 3
559 @ 4
562 @ 4
564 @ 4
553 @ 6
564 @ 9
```